# displayng multiple conten type in drupal views

Tags: drupal-7

i have 3 conteny types in drupal A B C which has few field commen in them like catagory , topic 


ContentA 
titleA
bodyA
catagory
topic


ContentB 
titleB
bodyB
catagory
topic


ContentC 
titleC
bodyC
catagory
topic

NOW I want to display these in a drupal view like below

> ContentA    ContentB     ContentC  
>     TitleA      TitleB       titleC   
>      bodyA       BodyB        bodyC

i will use category and topic as exposed filter

i pulled all the fields in my view but it shows nothing or if i place a filter on content type then it will display only that content type

i tried many techniques in aggregation too nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Use same fields in all content type using "existing fields" option.

In Views select common fields, under filter select required content types.

That's it.

Cheers!!!

Comment: but in this way view dosent give me one one node from each content type it just give me all 3 nodes from same content type

Comment: You can use Group by content type in View. Also if you provide some screen-shots supporting your requirement will be helpful.

Comment: can not produce screenshot but basically i want to show 1 node from each category , you can imagin like in a website we have  few catagoried like sports , health traval etc. and i want to show 1 artical/node from each category . group by content type is not working because this group is applied after view retived data/rows so the roes view is retrieving dosent contains each catagory it is just 3 nodes from only one category . one way i found is to use representative node relationship but in that too i am getting a error like  "invalid column name tid ". any help is appreciated

Comment: Create a block under view with 1 category, then create other required view and attached to the block.